# Declaring a variable for sma() and ema()

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I want to draw either SMA lines or EMA lines depending on what is chosen in the options.

```
sma_or_ema = input(group = "MA", title = "Type of MA", options = ["SMA", "EMA"], defval = "SMA")
ma_source = input(group = "MA", title = "Source", type = input.source, defval = close)
ma1_period = input(group = "MA", title = "SMA #1 period", type = input.integer, minval=3, maxval=200, defval = 20)
ma2_period = input(group = "MA", title = "SMA #2 period", type = input.integer, minval=3, maxval=200, defval = 50)
ma3_period = input(group = "MA", title = "SMA #3 period", type = input.integer, minval=3, maxval=200, defval = 100)
ma4_period = input(group = "MA", title = "SMA #4 period", type = input.integer, minval=3, maxval=200, defval = 200)

string ma_title = "SMA"

ma1_series = na
ma2_series = na
ma3_series = na
ma4_series = na

if sma_or_ema == "SMA"
    ma1_series := sma(ma_source, ma1_period)
    ma2_series := sma(ma_source, ma2_period)
    ma3_series := sma(ma_source, ma3_period)
    ma4_series := sma(ma_source, ma4_period)
else
    ma_title := "EMA"
    ma1_series := ema(ma_source, ma1_period)
    ma2_series := ema(ma_source, ma2_period)
    ma3_series := ema(ma_source, ma3_period)
    ma4_series := ema(ma_source, ma4_period)
    
plot(ma1_series, title = "MA #1", color = #5a0e41, linewidth = 1, trackprice = true)
plot(ma2_series, title = "MA #2", color = #752b59, linewidth = 1, trackprice = true)
plot(ma3_series, title = "MA #3", color = #8f4471, linewidth = 1, trackprice = true)
plot(ma4_series, title = "MA #4", color = #ab5d8b, linewidth = 1, trackprice = true)
```

plot cannot be called inside if statements. Variables cannot be declared inside if statements. Initializing the ma_series variables with sma() calls would work but it would cause unnecessary processing if EMA is chosen. How can I declare those variables?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the ma switch inside the function and pass your input as an argument:

```
//@version=4
study("ma-ema", overlay = true)

sma_or_ema = input(group = "MA", title = "Type of MA", options = ["SMA", "EMA"], defval = "SMA")
ma_source  = input(group = "MA", title = "Source", type = input.source, defval = close)
ma1_period = input(group = "MA", title = "SMA #1 period", type = input.integer, minval=3, maxval=200, defval = 20)
ma2_period = input(group = "MA", title = "SMA #2 period", type = input.integer, minval=3, maxval=200, defval = 50)
ma3_period = input(group = "MA", title = "SMA #3 period", type = input.integer, minval=3, maxval=200, defval = 100)
ma4_period = input(group = "MA", title = "SMA #4 period", type = input.integer, minval=3, maxval=200, defval = 200)

f_ma(_type, _source, _length) =>
    if _type == "SMA"
        sma(_source, _length)
    else
        ema(_source, _length)

ma1_series = f_ma(sma_or_ema, ma_source, ma1_period)
ma2_series = f_ma(sma_or_ema, ma_source, ma2_period)
ma3_series = f_ma(sma_or_ema, ma_source, ma3_period)
ma4_series = f_ma(sma_or_ema, ma_source, ma4_period)

plot(ma1_series)
plot(ma2_series)
plot(ma3_series)
plot(ma4_series)
```